# Positive Semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetrix matrix, if $\forall i$,

$a_{ii}\geq |a_{ij}|,\forall j$

satisfies, can we say that $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix? I tried to find a counter example, but failed.

Comment: A standard result guarantees the positivity is diagonal dominance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$